# Bootstrap 4 responsive table width per column to have specific width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm planning to create a table where some column needs to have a fixed width and not get auto adjusted.

I tried with this method but it's not working. It still seems to auto adjust width based on the text length.

How should I solve this?

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="m-0">
                <th class="w-20">a</th>
                <th class="w-10">b</th>
                <th class="w-20">c</th>
                <th class="w-40">d</th>
                <th class="w-10">e</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="m-0">
                <th class="w-20">a. Width with 20</th>
                <th class="w-10">b. Smaller width column</th>
                <th class="w-20">c. Should be small but I'm adding the maximum text here just to test if w-20 is working.</th>
                <th class="w-40">d. Biggest width but not working!</th>
                <th class="w-10">e. Another small column</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those class do not exist in bootstrap, you only have them for 25%,50%,75% and 100%. **you need to create them**:

```css
.w-20 {
  width: 20%;
}

.w-10 {
  width: 10%
}

.w-40 {
  width: 40%;
}

table {
  table-layout:fixed;/* will switch the table-layout algorythm */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="m-0">
        <th class="w-20">a</th>
        <th class="w-10">b</th>
        <th class="w-20">c</th>
        <th class="w-40">d</th>
        <th class="w-10">e</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="m-0">
        <th class="w-20">a. Width with 20</th>
        <th class="w-10">b. Smaller width column</th>
        <th class="w-20">c. Should be small but I'm adding the maximum text here just to test if w-20 is working.</th>
        <th class="w-40">d. Biggest width but not working!</th>
        <th class="w-10">e. Another small column</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

See

> https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/sizing/
>
> **Sizing**
>
> Easily make an element as wide or as tall (relative to its parent) with our width and height utilities. Includes support for 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% by default.

and

> https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout
>
> `table-layout`
>
> The `table-layout` property controls the algorithm used to lay out the table cells, rows, and columns.

Comment: Alright. I thought those classes exists but didn't show anything in the console. Thought I was doing it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use custom classes when you want fixed width.

Use class

> .w-20{ width: 200px !important; }

Comment: `!important` is just bad coding method in my opinion. Thanks though.

Comment: @ElaineByene sometimes you may need it to override bootstrap styles. BS source has lot of `!important`

Answer (score 0):

To support in each and every browser, prefer using the following:

```
.w-20 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 20% !important;
  flex: 0 0 20% !important;
  max-width: 20%;
}
```